# how to use count distinct with namedQueries in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have this :

```
class Contribution {
  String name
  ...
  static namedQueries{
     findAllByName{
         'in' "name", ['bla','bla','fafa','fofo']
     }
  }
}
```

I use the method listDistinct and it's right. 
But for pagination I need to have the totalCount.

How to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it OK to add distinct to the named query? Like

```
  static namedQueries{
     findAllByName{
         'in' "name", ['bla','bla','fafa','fofo']
          projections {
            groupProperty("name")
          }
     }
  }
```

Comment: but with namedQueries, on list operations with max and offset it seems that's not a PagedResultList but a ArrayList. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sometimes I construct a `PagedResultList` myself - it's surprisingly easily created with a `List` and a `totalCount` :) Anyway, what is the sense of `PagedResultList` when you're explicitly specifying `max` and `offset`?